# What is the selling rate per pound for individual colors?

Tags: shopping, value

I separated all my LEGO bricks by color so I can get max profit to pay closing costs on my family's home.  Is there a going rate per pound for individual colors?

Answer (score 6):

Colour seperation matters more in which audience will be interested (AFOL's knowing they used some colour(s) more than others vs. parents wanting a pile for their kids) than for price.

Lots of things matter a lot more then the bricks being seperated by colour, some examples:

- Whether the bricks have play wear
- Whether the bricks have been miscoloured by sunlight
- Whether the bricks have been exposed to smoking
- The actual selection of bricks - i.e. are they all standard bricks or are they something less common in (some of) the pile(s)
- Where you are in the world
- ...

So we don't have nearly enough information to give a good answer.

They are other questions on the site where people give estimates.

Comment: I would add to this that selling by the pound usually produces the lowest possible profit. Maximum profit is by selling parts individually, or by selling complete desirable retired sets in good to excellent condition. Separating by color has very little benefit, unless the color is rare; old grays, old brown, olive-green, dark-green/red/blue, and sand-green/red-blue. But even then, condition is very important, as well as what kind of mix of parts we are talking about. If OP mostly has standard colors, it's better to separate them by part, and/or condition, rather than color.